# Azure data factory Disable pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure data factory and have created two pipelines in it for testing purposes. I dont want to remove them but somehow disable them. I cant seem to find a way to disable one without deleting it.
Is there a setting I am missing. Please guide.
Thanks.  This is how my piplelines look.
[image]

Comment: remove the trigger from your pipeline or, if the trigger only launches this pipeline, you can pause it instead

Answer (score 1):

You can stop/pause the triggers associated with those pipelines as shown below:
Go to `Manage` hub and then to `Triggers` and stop the trigger associate with the pipelines and then publish the changes to reflect.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @KranthiPakala-MSFT. I was hoping to reuse the trigger on two pipelines this way I dont need to create two similar triggers and just have to disable one pipeline. Sounds like with your recommendation there would be one trigger per pipeline.

Comment: Yes, @/sarah. If you want to reuse the same trigger for other pipeline, then the option is to remove the trigger from the pipeline in which you want to pause.

Comment: The synapse triggers can be disabled in the same way ? Is that correct ?